# Handling Angular 2 csrf for cross origins

Tags: angular, laravel, cross-domain, csrf

below is the architecture of our application.

1. the web interface **[the client]** is standalone Angular 2 application **[domain.com]**
2. the **[proxy]** which held the client credential **[the web interface secret]** **[domain2.com]**
3. the **[API]** itself which has the auth server **[domain3.com]**

the application flow are like below:

1. user enter his credential username+password into **[the client]** login page which then send it to the **[proxy]**.
2. then proxy will append the  credential to the request and forward it to the **[API]**.
3. **[API]** will be able to obtain the access+refresh tokens after validating the user credential & return it to the **[proxy]**
4. **[proxy]** return the response along with the header **[Set-Cookie:XSRF-TOKEN]**
5. **[client]** should then able to read the **[XSRF-TOKEN]** & send it along with every request as **[X-XSRF-TOKEN]** header.

everything is working as expected both on the auth server, proxy & the client except for step 5:

Angular should be able to handle this automatically as per the documentation

```js
{ provide: XSRFStrategy, useValue: new CookieXSRFStrategy('XSRF-TOKEN', 'X-CSRF-TOKEN')}
```

where is angular will be able to get the value of the **[XSRF-TOKEN]** cookie and create the **[X-CSRF-TOKEN]** header along with every request we made through the application.

although & as I building the architecture using different origins, angular could not be able to read cookie from another origin.

The problem with this approach I am facing is that since the server is in different domain, I cannot read the cookie through XSRFStrategy provider. Is there a way to read a value of that cookie?

If not, so the current architecture is wrong & I need to build the **[client]** & **[proxy]** in the same domain which I am avoided this approach because I need to separate the presentation layer from any backend code.

So, simply my question is how to implement csrf protection for this kind of situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your port you mention "access+refresh tokens", which sounds like you'd be using OAuth. In a cross-origin scenario, CSRF is often simply not an issue. If there is any kind of HTTP Header your client needs to send to authenticate, you can safely disable CSRF.

A CSRF attack would make your browser send cookie stored for the [API] domain, and with some hacks the attacker might also send a "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest". But if your API also needs a "Authorization: Bearer ..." token, you can drop the whole CSRF nuisance.